# Valid Characters in Unicode don't display in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, unicode

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or there's an issue with certain unicode ranges in Inkscape

Characters like  (U+1F377, U+1F37A, U+1F37B) do not display in Inkscape, even when used with a font like Arial Unicode MS that has the characters in it. Other apps on the same Mac display them correctly.

Is there are issue with this character range in Inkscape?

Comment: I don't have the font, so cannot check. What does it say in the Unicode characters character table? Are the glyphs there?

Comment: Hmmm . . . maybe a Mac problem. The characters do definitely display in [Inkscape in Win10](https://imgur.com/Vk3RDUs), although they are monochrome, and have a rather odd cut-off effect at the top. However when saved as SVG, they [do display properly in a browser](https://svgshare.com/i/ZwQ.svg).

Comment: @Moini The glyphs are there in other apps. I can cut and paste into other apps and they display.

Comment: @BillyKerr That was a good question, I hadn't tried that. Yes, if i save the file, and load it in the browser, the character displays correctly. In Inkscape it is displayed as a ? in a box.